# Tables filter results query

Tags: php, forms, sorting, mysqli

I am looking to filter the results once the value to search is entered, so that the table headers links only return the search result. Currently it returns the entire table.
How can I do it? By changing the form from post to get? Any ideas?

Usually, the table would show 20+ records, which can be sorted by clicking the table header. When the search is completed, I would like the table header to only sort the search results. I.E. If I searched 'Tom', and it returned 3 results, I would like the link in the header to only sort those 3 returned results.

```
<?php


include 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {

$valueToSearch = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['valueToSearch']);
// search in all table columns
// using concat mysql function
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts 
        WHERE CONCAT(FirstName, Surname, Email, HomePhone, MobPhone) 
        LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";

$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

} else {




$orderBy = "FirstName";
$order = "asc";

 if(!empty($_GET["orderby"])) {
$orderBy = $_GET["orderby"];
}
if(!empty($_GET["order"])) {
$order = $_GET["order"];
}

$firstOrder = "asc";
$SurOrder = "asc";
$emailOrder = "desc";

if($orderBy == "FirstName" and $order == "asc") {
    $firstOrder = "desc";
}
if($orderBy == "Surname" and $order == "asc") {
    $surOrder = "desc";
}
if($orderBy == "Email" and $order == "desc") {
    $emailOrder = "asc";
}

// Build an SQL Query
$sql = "SELECT * from contacts ORDER BY " . $orderBy . " " . $order;


// Run the Query
$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

}

?>



    <form action="front-contact.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Value To Search"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>

    <form action='' method=post>
    <table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th><a href="?orderby=FirstName&order=<?php echo $firstOrder; ?>">First Name</a></th>
    <th><a href="?orderby=Surname&order=<?php echo $surOrder; ?>">Surname</th>
    <th><a href="?orderby=Email&order=<?php echo $emailOrder; ?>">Email Address</th>
    <th>Home Number</th>
    <th>Mobile Number</th>
    </tr>

  <?php
       


        
        // Loop through each returned record and store the data in $row.. // 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {


    // Output the column-name of $row using the array-notation // 

        echo "<form action='' method=post>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['FirstName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Surname']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['HomePhone']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['MobPhone']."</td>";
        echo " </form>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }

       echo "</table>";


?>
```

Comment: What's the name of the file you included in the OP? It should be `front-contact.php` if you want it to use this code. Is this code that page?

Comment: Ye, that's the name of the page.

Comment: Have you tried echoing the values for `$_POST['search']` and `$_POST['valueToSearch']` to see if they are actually the values that you're looking for? I assume there are no errors upon submission either, correct?

Comment: Hi Michael, Sorry.. i may have mis-worded the question. The results for both the search and the sort are fine. But once the search query is run, when click the table header to sort the values, it jumps back to all the all the results in the database, rather than the results of the search. I would like it to only sort the search results.

Answer (score 0):

That makes more sense. Thank you for clarifying. I wonder if it would keep the search results when you sort, if you populated the `valueToSearch` input with the search query. Something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Value To Search" value="<?php echo isset($valueToSearch) ? $valueToSearch : '' ?>">
```

The input is likely being cleared when you do your initial search, so when you go to sort your table, it's re-querying your database, but because the input is empty, it's then pulling all of the database records again. That's my thought. Let me know if it doesn't work.